# Example for using WCF RIA Services with Prism?

Tags: wcf-ria-services, composite

Is there a current and good example how to use WCF RIA Services together with Prism? There's a lot of information about each topic. But at the moment I can't see how to put everything together into a "real world" LOB application.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the [Telerik Sales Dashboard demo](http://www.telerik.com/products/salesdashboard.aspx). It implements the "Composite Application Guidance for WPF and Silverlight ("Prism")" and also uses WCF Services. You can download the source of the application and run it on your side.